# Do I need a visa if arriving at Narita and connecting to a flight from Haneda?

Tags: visas, transit, paperwork, japan, transit-visas

My flight arrives at Narita and, after a 9 hour layover, I connect to another flight from Haneda airport to my final destination, Kuala Lumpur. Do I need to apply for a visa if I’m going to be transferred from one airport to another?

Comment: Please indicate your nationality.

Answer (score 2):

If you require a visa to enter Japan, then you'll need one to switch airports, **unless** it's an overnight transfer, in which case you can get a 72-hour entry stamp on arrival.

Comment: Only overnight, but not morning to evening of the same day?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Apparently according to TIMATIC. The Japanese Immigration Bureau was very vague to me about this on the phone, and I have no evidence pointing to otherwise (or I would ask my IATA contact to double-check this)